# Assigning group ID with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

Pretty basic performance question from an R newbie. I'd like to assign a group ID to each row in a data frame by unique combinations of fields. Here's my current approach:

```
> # An example data frame
> df <- data.frame(name=c("Anne", "Bob", "Chris", "Dan", "Erin"), 
                   st.num=c("101", "102", "105", "102", "150"), 
                   st.name=c("Main", "Elm", "Park", "Elm", "Main"))
> df
   name st.num st.name
1  Anne    101    Main
2   Bob    102     Elm
3 Chris    105    Park
4   Dan    102     Elm
5  Erin    150    Main
> 
> # A function to generate a random string
> getString <- function(size=10) return(paste(sample(c(0:9, LETTERS, letters), size, replace=TRUE), collapse=''))
>
> # Assign a random string for each unique street number + street name combination
> df <- ddply(df, 
              c("st.num", "st.name"), 
              function(x) transform(x, household=getString()))
> df
   name st.num st.name  household
1  Anne    101    Main 1EZWm4BQel
2   Bob    102     Elm xNaeuo50NS
3   Dan    102     Elm xNaeuo50NS
4 Chris    105    Park Ju1NZfWlva
5  Erin    150    Main G2gKAMZ1cU
```

While this works well for data frames with relatively few rows or a small number of groups, I run into performance problems with larger data sets ( > 100,000 rows) that have many unique groups.

Any suggestions to improve the speed of this task? Possibly with plyr's experimental idata.frame()? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the `id` function (also in plyr):

```
df$id <- id(df[c("st.num", "st.name")], drop = TRUE)
```

**Update:**

The `id` function is considered deprecated since dplyr version 0.5.0.
The function `group_indices` provides the same functionality.

Comment: Apparently I need to go back and read the plyr documentation more carefully - this is exactly what I was looking for. I evaluated this solution and JoFrhwld's on my test dataset: a data frame with 164,961 observations and 91,876 unique groups based on 3 grouping variables. I used each of these methods to assign a group ID variable 100 times.

The mean elapsed time for id() was .958 (sd .0310). Mean elapsed time for pasting the grouping fields was 1.94 (sd .0946).

Thanks to both!

Answer (score 2):

Is it necessary that the ID be a random 10 character string? If not, why not just paste together the columns of the data frame. If the IDs must be the same length in characters, convert factors to numeric, then paste them together:

```
df$ID <- paste(as.numeric(df$st.num), as.numeric(df$st.name), sep = "")
```

Then, if you really need to have 10 character IDs, I'd generate just the n number of IDs, and rename the levels of ID with them

```
df$ID <- as.factor(df$ID)
n <- nlevels(df$ID)

getID <- function(n, size=10){
  out <- {}
  for(i in 1:n){
    out <- c(paste(sample(c(0:9, LETTERS, letters), size, replace=TRUE), collapse=''))
  }
  return(out)
}

newLevels <- getID(n = n)

levels(df$ID) <- newLevels
```

Also, as an aside, you don't need to use `function(x)` with ddply that way with `transform()`. This code would work just the same:

```
ddply(df, c("st.num", "st.name"), transform, household=getString())
```